# Use Laravel Socialite to query Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, laravel, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I was wondering if I can use Laravel 5 + Socialite to query the latest posts from a Facebook Fanpage via Facebook Graph API.

I have not found any example. Is Socialite just for User Authentication and not for Grpah Api requests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `laravel-socialite` package is only for OAuth Authentication and does not cover the API functionality you desire.

There are, however, many other packages you could integrate into your `laravel` application to achieve this.